# How to map a field of Object from one page with the Object from another page based on the Id field in Java 8

Tags: java, spring, list, hashmap, java-stream

I have two [*Spring Pages*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html) like this : `Page<Account>` and `Page<Bank>`.

```
class Account{
    String name;
    String bankId;
    Bank bank;
}
```

I would like to `setBank()` for every `Account` object in the `Page<Account>` with the corresponding object from `Page<Bank>` based on the `bankId`.

I think I can use Java 8 streams for that.

So far, I've tried :

```
Map<String, Account> acc = account.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Account::getBankId, a -> a));

List<Bank> bk = bank.stream()
           .map(b-> new Account(b.get(b.getBankId()), bk))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I guess there will be more than one account in each bank. So instead of `Map<String, Account>` you need a `Map<String, List<Account>>` - `accountsByBankId`. Which can be created by using build-in collector [`Collectors.groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function)).

Then you can map every bank to its `id` `Map<String, Bank>` with `Collectors.toMap()`.

And finally, set the bank object retrieved from the `bankById` map to every account in the map `accountsByBankId`.

```
Map<String, List<Account>> accountsByBankId = account.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Account::getBankId));
    
Map<String, Bank> bankById = bank.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Bank::getBankId, Function.identity()));
        
accountsByBankId.forEach((bankId, accounts) -> {
    accounts.forEach(acc -> acc.setBank(bankById.get(bankId)));
});
```